# Why does my Xcode recognize optional delegate method as unrecognized selector?

Tags: objective-c, crash, selector, ios6

This is my crash log.

```
2012-09-24 00:06:16.711 DMJ[10021:c07] -[DMJAppDelegate application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x84abe70
2012-09-24 00:06:16.713 DMJ[10021:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DMJAppDelegate application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x84abe70'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2553012 0x1e04e7e 0x25de4bd 0x1e187ea 0x2542cf9 0x254294e 0x82a332 0x91266d 0x90d046 0x90d246 0x85601f 0x476e8e 0x4769b7 0x875573 0x4a1428 0xa420cc 0x1e18663 0x254e45a 0xa40bcf 0xa4298d 0x824ceb 0x825002 0x823ed6 0x835315 0x83624b 0x827cf8 0x2c88df9 0x2c88ad0 0x24c8bf5 0x24c8962 0x24f9bb6 0x24f8f44 0x24f8e1b 0x8237da 0x82565c 0x2ded 0x2d25 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 5):

Optional in the context of protocols means that you don't need to implement the method. 
But you must also take care not to call these methods or you are going to get an exception.
Normally before calling an optional protocol method you would do the following:

```
if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:)])
    result = [object application:myApp supportedInterfaceOritentationsForWindow:myWin];
```

As mentioned, the method probably gets called because your info.plist does not contain the correct keys (UIInterfaceOrientation).

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure your Delegate class conforms to the UIApplicationDelegate Protocol?

Your `DMJAppDelegate.h` should have

```
@interface DMJAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

Also as mentioned in the [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786) about UIApplicationDelegate, if your application Info.plist does not have the key `UIInterfaceOrientation` specifying the valid orientations then it will call the `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow` to the delegate (thus not being optional in this case) so you need to make sure you've specified the orientations in your Info.plist if you have not implemented the delegate method

This is how it should be specified within Xcode when you open your Info.plist (separate for iPhone and iPad if you are developing a Universal app)

[image: Xcode Info.plist Orientation]

Alternatively you can see the Supported Interface Orientations by choosing your Target in the Project Summary

[image: Xcode Project Summary]

Comment: thx for your advice.  I followed your advice. but the problem remains same state. what should I do... :(